# PayPal LogIn Scope Error

Tags: paypal

I am trying to add the PayPal Login button to my website.(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/)

When I try to LogIn I get the error:
"Relying party validation error: scope in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request and try again."

I'm not sure what the Scope error is referring to. Below is the code I've used. If anyone could help, I would very much appreciate it as I've tried a lot of potential solutions.

```
<div class="row">
    <span id='myContainer'></span>
    <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js'></script>
    <script>
    paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
      login.render ({
        "appid": "myappid",
        "authend": "sandbox",
        "scopes": "profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",        
        "containerid": "myContainer",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "returnurl": "myurl"
      });
    });
    </script>  
</div>
```

Note: This is different to the client id and/or return url error: "Relying Party Validation error: client_id provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request.". Thus, I'm 100% sure that the client id and return url that I am using are correct.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar problems:

1. Go to your REST API PayPal app
2. Select Login with PayPal checkbox, click on "Advanced options" next to it
3. Select needed scope options